# To which noun is "qui" attached to in "le Baiser d'or du Bois, qui se recueille"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe, poésie

In this line from the poem "Tête de faune" by Rimbaud, how do I know who "recueille"? Is it "le Baiser" or "le Bois"? To whom does the "qui" refer?

If it is refering the "Bois", how do I refer to the "Baiser"?

Comment: More context is needed ; to identify clearly what is meant by this expression provide enough sentences before and what comes after; otherwise give an explanation.

Comment: @LPH This poem by Rimbaud is easily found on the internet, this is [the version](https://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/Poemes/arthur_rimbaud/tete_de_faune) the OP refers to, but two different versions have been published, [here is the other one](https://short-edition.com/fr/classique/arthur-rimbaud/tete-de-faune).  This is important to note as there is a coma in one and not in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that is determined by context. Relative pronouns such as *qui* can modify an entire phrasal noun or just part of it. Some examples taken from « Les Chansons de Bilitis » :

- « Je te bercerai d’une main sur mon genou qui se lève et s’abaisse. » : The relative clause is clearly attached to « mon genou » and not « une main sur mon genou » by context.
- « Quand aurai-je comme toi des seins de jeune fille qui gonflent la robe et tentent le baiser ? » : The relative clause is clearly attached to « des seins de jeune fille » and not « jeune fille » as the verbs are conjugated in the plural. The « jeune fille » is also by context an inappropriate subject for the verbs.

In this example from [Rimbaud](https://www.lieder.net/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=13676), « se recueillir » probably refers to « le Baiser ». This is indicated clearly in the translations of the poem that I found while looking for references:

> And the Golden Kiss of the Woods, started by a bullfinch, resolves once again to rest. ([Mason](https://books.google.com/books?id=fn9lqfdLwgQC&lpg=PA103&ots=dIXd4NQarw&dq=%22the%20golden%20kiss%20of%20the%20woods%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q&f=false))
>
> And one sees frightened by a bullfinch the Golden Kiss of the Woods, communing with itself. ([Ahearn](https://books.google.com/books?id=-vV1FdhXmrwC&lpg=PA117&ots=ZdCZMMo_qt&dq=%22the%20golden%20kiss%20of%20the%20woods%22&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q&f=false))
>
> … and you can see frightened by a bullfinch the golden Kiss of the Woods, in meditation. ([Appelbaum](https://books.google.com/books?id=XnyobUnpk-0C&lpg=PA141&ots=WayDRrGGzi&dq=%22the%20golden%20kiss%20of%20the%20woods%22&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q&f=false))

One might also observe that in the clause, « le Baiser d'or du Bois » is already treated as a unit by « l'on voit épeuré ». Because of this precedent and the comma, which implies a pause to me, « qui se recueille » probably also applies to the entire phrasal noun. If it were instead attached to « le Bois », I would expect it to more or less proceed without a break, to make the attachment clearer.

> et l'on voit épeuré par un bouvreuil
> le Baiser d'or du Bois, qui se recueille.

Answer (score 1):

There are [two known versions](http://abardel.free.fr/tout_rimbaud/dossier_verlaine_1871.htm) of this poem *Tête de faune* by Rimbaud, the version you refer to, with a comma before *se recueille* is from a manuscript by Rimbaud.
The version published in les *[Poètes maudits](https://bibliothequenumerique.tv5monde.com/livre/286/Les-Poetes-maudits)* has no comma.

I personally do not think the place of the comma changes the way we should interpret this line but I agree with Maroon's answer saying that it is the *Baiser d'or* who is the subject of *recueillir*.

My own interpretation of the poem is that *Le baiser* at the start is asleep (*le baiser dort*, line 3). While the *baiser* (to me it personifies the poet but other interpretations are possible of course) is asleep the faun arrives and kisses the red flowers. Amidst the faun's intervention *the baiser* – who by the last line of the poem is referred to as le *Baiser d'or* – remains asleep, or at least half asleep (→ *il se recueille*).

But as I said other interpretations are possible as this one given [here](http://paintedplates.blogspot.com/2013/08/les-cesures-de-1872-deuxieme-partie.html) :

> Suite à [l'acte du faune], le bois se pâme dans une longue extase (dernier vers : « Le Baiser d’or du Bois, qui se recueille. »)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> After the faun has perpetrated his act the wood swoons into a long ecstasy (my translation).